# JS selection options onchange and post data

Tags: javascript, html, selection

Hi I have an selection form which also changes between forms, meaning it's to choose between a product (also is the certain product) and post data after that.

```
            <select class="select" name="product" style="width: 270px" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
                                    <option name="Product 1" selected value="orderform1.html">Product 1</option>
                                    <option name="Product 2" value="orderform2.html">Product 2</option>

                                </select>
```

Switch between the product works fine, but post posts the data from the value, so i tried to to switch name and value and

```
location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].name;
```

But thats not working, any ideas hints what ever, thx for any help :)

Comment: I believe `name` is not a valid attribute for the `option` element; please try using something else instead like `id`.

Comment: thanks, worked with id :)